# Data copy from a table to another with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy 2 table from one excel sheet to another.
I cannot use them as listobjects, as these are automatically generated files.
I thought this could help (after openingthe source file, I named activesheet as sourcefile, thiswb is what contains the macros and the destination file):

```
Dim isin_data As Range
Dim position_data As Range

Set isin_data = sourcefile.Sheets("ISIN data").Range("A5:CA200")
Set position_data = sourcefile.Sheets("Position data").Range("A5:BD400")

thiswb.Sheets("HLA_ISIN_data").Range("A2:CA197") = isin_data
thiswb.Sheets("HLA_position_data").Range("A2:BD397") = position_data
```

Nothing happens, could you help me why? This works, but not elegant, plus not efficient:

```
sourcefile.Sheets("ISIN data").Range("A5:CA200").Copy
thiswb.Sheets("HLA_ISIN_data").Activate
Range("A2:CA197").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

sourcefile.Sheets("Position data").Range("A5:BD400").Copy
thiswb.Sheets("HLA_position_data").Activate
Range("A2:BD397").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your source ranges all formulas or just data?

Comment: Be explicit: `thiswb.Sheets("HLA_ISIN_data").Range("A2:CA197").Value = isin_data.Value`.